# Merge columns in a proportion table

Tags: r

I am trying to generate a proportion table of the distribution of companies among countries. However, some proportions are very small. I'd like to merge the columns where the proportion is below 0.02 into a single column named Other.

I have tried many things but now I am just back at the beginning.

```
tab <- prop.table(table(Country))
othertab <- table(Others,sum(tab[tab<0.02]))
newtab <- table(tab[tab>0.02],othertab)
```

Thank you for your help.